# Elastic search in hybrid sleep mode - embedded in application

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to bring elastic search instance up just for indexing the content.

Something like:
Elastic search wakes up (say every 30 seconds), updates the indexes and sleeps.
Application uses some utility provided by elastic search to query search results from the index.

Advantage: No dependency on elastic search availability.

Comment: How are you going to search your index if ES is down?

Comment: Some utility from elastic search that can be embedded inside application itself, which has the ability to search in the index files created by elastic search.

Comment: I'm curious which utility that is, do you mind sharing?

Comment: I don't know whether such utility even exists, but I wanted to understand if this is possible or not from elastic search perspective. Or this makes no sense.

Comment: You need to have Elasticsearch up and running if you want to search the index. What are you worried about for not willing to let ES run?

Comment: I have summarized my use-case and issues that I can face when ES is not up in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166968/how-to-build-elastic-search-indexes-for-data-stored-in-java-application-cache

To solve problem in that thread, one of the approaches I thought of was this. Maybe its completely vague and there are better solutions.