# How to build elastic search indexes for data stored in java application cache?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, filesystems, java-threads

I have reader APIs written in Java that reads data from file system. Data is written to a file system by perl scripts.

To attain better performance from reader APIs, I maintain an in-memory cache (basically a hashmap inside java application itself) for caching last 7 days of data from file system. For achieving this, whenever application starts, a dedicated thread takes care of reading last 7 days of data from file system and updating the cache. And I also created a thread that wakes up every 30 seconds and refreshes the cache (reads entries from FS and updates/adds to the cache).

Now, we want to build search on this data (to start with, maybe just the data that is stored inside cache, i.e. last 7 days of data) using elastic search.

One way that I thought off for achieving this is:

1. Whenever java application comes up a thread that reads last 7 days of data from file system can call elastic search APIs for creating the indexes as well. This thread will delete all old indexes from ES. This is to ensure data in cache and data in ES are same when application started.
2. Similarly a thread that wakes up every 30s to refresh the cache, should call elastic search API to refresh the elastic search indexes as well.

I am not sure how can I make this system fault tolerant. That is there could be a time when a call to elastic search from a thread that wakes up every 30s fails. With this, data inside application cache and data indexed with Elastic Search won't be in sync. How can I prevent this?

Is there some better approach to build search on this data?

Should I use lucene instead?

Comment: Why not getting rid of the in-memory cache and simply use ES for caching and indexing/searching?

Comment: That would still need a thread from an application to call ES API for updating indexes in ES. Qn still remains same, how can we make this process as fault tolerant.

Comment: Why not simply having a separate Logstash read data off the file system and send it to Elasticsearch? That way your application can keep the focus on the business logic and not with any data management chores.

Comment: Actually there is no single file, and data is scattered across multiple files. And these files are created/updated at runtime by perl scripts.

Comment: Maybe we can write a script to consolidate data from different sources into a single file and then use logstash on top of it.

Comment: Logstash can source data from different local/remote filesystem folders and/or other local/remote data sources.

Comment: Yes it can, but as I said earlier these files are created dynamically and names of each file is only known to Perl engine. Maybe we can write some logic for creating file names, but I am not sure if Logstash is this powerful that we can even put some code

Comment: Logstash can watch a folder and pick up files as soon as they are created. You don't need to know the file name in advance.

Comment: But what about aggregating data from different files to create a document needed for elastic search? This is required because data is normalized and scattered in different files.

Comment: But what about aggregating data from different files to create a document needed for elastic search? This is required because data is normalized and scattered in different files.

Comment: Logstash can also do that using the `aggregate` filter